# What the best multi-thread application debugger for C++ apps

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I'm looking for a good multi-thread-aware debugger, capable of showing performance charts of application threads on Linux, don't know if such a thing exists, perhaps as a Eclipse plugin.
The idea would be to track per thread memory allocation a CPU usage as well as being able to interrupt a thread and examine its stack trace, local vars, etc.
It does not have to be an eclipse plugin or a free tool, do any of you have heard of something similar?

Answer (score 1):

[Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) does provide information on a [per-thread basis](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-1.0/creator-debugging.html#threads). It also has the features you would expect from any standard debugger. (Watches, breakpoints, etc.)

Although designed for compiling Qt applications, it can be used for just about any C++ project. (I have used it for compiling/editing a non-Qt app before.)

Comment: Never though QT Creator had that kind of tools, pretty neat, I'll take a look at it.
The last time you used it with multi-threaded apps were you using simple pthreads or some specific Qt threading classes?

Comment: @Core: Hmmm... I think it was Qt threads, but I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work for native threads.

Answer (score 1):

[TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx) (and [MemoryScape](http://www.roguewave.com/products/memoryscape.aspx)) doesn't do precisely what you're asking for in its' default presentation, but it provides the data you need.  It costs money, but a better C++ debugger for Linux cannot be found.

Free trials are available, and there are a number of cool and useful [videos](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview/resources/videos.aspx) on their support site.

Comment: I've downloaded totalview demos in the past, never got a chance to actually review it, I'll take a look at the videos and see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, you've got access to one of the most powerful debugging tools in the trade - [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read about it, especially about it's [additional tools](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) like Helgrind.

Sure, the visualisation is lacking compared to commercial tools, but you can't beat it's level of detail.

Comment: I've been using valgrind from long ago, beautiful tool, however for the purpose of this research I haven't seen any graphical tools but alleyoop which is not compliant with my current need, perhaps its time to work on a project for better visualization?

Comment: @Coredumped - extending existing great tools to be even more great is *always* a good project ;)

Comment: Eclipse CDT has a more or less decent integration of Valgrind and a UI that draws charts quite nicely. Add to that Callgraph and Systemtap and you can go quite deep in performance analysis even on kernel level (for Systemtap see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/introduction.html for a nice beginner-friendly introduction).